# Campo calculado a partir de otra tabla

Tags: ms-access

Tengo dos tablas: Tabla1 y Tabla2.

Quiero añadir en la Tabla2 un campo calculado usando información de la Tabla1.

Quiero hacer desde la Tabla2 algo como esto:

```
SiInm( [Tabla1]![Campo1]= "A"; "Es A"; "No es A")
```

Pero esto no funciona.

Para añadir la nueva columna a Tabla2 tengo que, desde la Tabla1:

```
SiInm([Campo1]= "A"; "Es A"; "No es A")
```

Ocultar la nueva columna creada, pq no me interesa que esté.

Luego hacer una consulta donde meto toda la información de la Tabla2 y la nueva columna de la Tabla1 que había ocultado antes.

Por lo que para añadir una nueva columna en Tabla2 tengo que hacerlo en la Tabla1 y luego hacer una consulta.

¿No hay una manera más directa?

Comment: No estoy seguro de lo que quieres decir, pero ¿has probado con DLOOKUP (DBÚSQ en español? Por otro lado y a título personal, campos calculados en las propias tablas pueden acabar dando problemas en cuanto abras el Access en una versión ligeramente más antigua, porque no los reconocerá. Pero campos calculados en consultas sí. ¿Puedes poner tus inputs y el output esperado?

Comment: DBÚSQ solo está disponible cuando hago una consulta. Desde la propia tabla no aparece. Supongo que no se puede hacer de forma directa y hay que pasar si o si por la consulta.